# Align movement direction elements(previous/next) before/after a relative positioned element (no flexbox)

Tags: html, css

I'm working on multi-item carousel, and I need to align 2 elements, previous,next - before,after a container that is in position relative;

I need:

- Previous to be vertical align in the middle before `items`
- Next to be vertical align in the middle after `items`
- for Next,Previous I want to use in the end an icon font

`items` using javascript will be moved left-right, so he needs to be relative positioned

I tried to use `display:inline-block` on items, but doesn't work as expected;
! Can be used floats instead of `display: inline-block` for class `item-container`.
I can't use flexbox, because I need to support older browsers.

```css
.carousel {
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.c-carousel__previous,
.c-carousel__next {
  display: inline-block;
}

.items {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.item-container {
  width: 16.66667%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="previous">
    previous
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item-container">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="next">
    next
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above answers are good, if all the elements are static, but I mentioned that

> 'items using javascript will be moved left-right, so it needs to be
>   relative positioned';

This movement of the 'items' class created multiple issues, in all the above cases(like 'hiding' next/previous, overflow hidding content that should be vissible;

So, the solution I found:

- remove `overflow: hidden` from carousel
- add a new container for items, items-container and use `overflow: hidden` on this one
- position next,previous `absolute`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```css
.carousel {
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.previous,
.next {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 25px;
}

.items {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;  
  width: 450px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item-container {
  width: 16.66667%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="previous">
    previous
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item-container">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="next">
    next
  </div>
</div>
```

and please adjust the `width` accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try `vertical-align: middle` in `.items` container with `overflow: hidden`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.carousel {
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.previous,
.next {
  display: inline-block;
}

.items {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item-container {
  width: 16.66667%;
  margin: 0 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="previous">previous</div>
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item-container">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="next">next</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: inline-block` on correct classes and give width to item.

Hope this would work:

```css
.carousel {
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.previous,
.next {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.items {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(500px - 100px);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item-container {
  width: 16.66667%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="previous">
    previous
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item-container">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-container">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="next">
    next
  </div>
</div>
```